# Steps to Deploy Express React Redux template to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, heroku, redux

Limited experience with Node and deploying to Heroku. I've built something up using this boilerplate: https://github.com/DimitriMikadze/express-react-redux-starter but am not really certain how to set up the template for deployment to Heroku.

Any basic steps would be super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Heroku's docs are actually really great! https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs . That will walk you through deploying their example repo, but the starter kit you linked to above will work almost exactly the same. I would walk through that tutorial to deploy Heroku's example repo first just to make sure you have their toolkit properly installed and generally understand how it works, it won't take long at all. Then I would move on to deploying the app you've built. The one change I know you'll have to make is what you put in your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile). Yours will need to look something like this:
`web: npm run build && npm start`
hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks much for this -- I ran through the Heroku getting started article and successfully deployed their sample application. However now when running through the same steps for my express-react-redux-starter kit app I am getting an application error. When I look at the Heroku logs I see that the systems fails on `PORT=8080 pm2 start ./server.js` which is from package.json -- any idea how to resolve this? Thank you again!

Comment: Is there anything else in the logs that might help?

Comment: Ah, in the readme for that starter kit: *Note: I'm using pm2 for production server, you should install it on server via 'npm install pm2 -g'. if you don't want to use pm2, just change pm2 with node in package.json file in scripts section.* So try changing `start` in package.json to 
    
        `"start": "PORT=8080 node start ./server.js",`

Comment: Here's the output from the Heroku logs: https://gist.github.com/kimispencer/a4d22b74f42821fe283fca68fa25746d Agree it seems to be an issue with pm2. I changed to `"start": "PORT=8080 node start ./server.js"` within package.json but the error is still there... just did a fresh push to `heroku master` and see the change to package.json in my git logs... any idea why the change isn't getting picked up? Thx!

Comment: Can you post the new logs after the node change? All the errors in that gist are talking about pm2

Comment: That's what's confusing me -- those are the logs after pushing the package.json change (to not refer to pm2). Could be a caching issue? On local master branch, pushed to heroku master. Apologies if this is a very basic mistake, really appreciate the tips!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123182/discussion-between-drew-schuster-and-vesperae).

Comment: @vesperae solved this himself in chat, leaving here for anyone else running into issues:
"Ah ha -- ok so after a bunch of digging around I realized it relates to how devDependencies vs Dependencies are setup (re the missing webpack). Additionally the line node start ./server.js was causing a crash but using node ./server.js works, and it's alive!"

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku + NodeJS getting started tutorial was incredibly helpful. After fiddling around with deploying to Heroku I realized my problems were as following:

1. pm2 dependency -- as suggested I removed it and replace the npm start script to just `PORT=8080 node start ./server.js`

However, that caused separate problems:

A. 'start' was undefined, B. I got a Heroku error "web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port", and C. missing Webpack + other dependencies

By simply removing the hardcoded port and "start" -- so the script is now just `node ./server.js` as well as fixing any devDependencies AND setting my Heroku config to `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION: false` it works now! Huzzah. Thanks for the assistance on this.